# Jeep cherokee 2004 crd sport Immobilizer relay

Tags: relay, immobilizer

i have a Jeep cherokee 2004 crd sport... I am looking for Immobilizer relay part number and position. It seems near impossible to find the info, there not even a 2004 haynes manual 
regards

Comment: Why not look at the old one - most parts places can match a standard relay.

Comment: hi, I would but iam unsure where its position or number is. The fuse / relay box inside the jeeps says look at the manual. The fuses / relays under the hood are marked up but the immobilizer is not there